# How to compare dynamic variables in a programmatic way in python

Tags: python, dynamic

I have a function that gets and compares 2 out of 6 and more websites data. After getting 2 sites data I begin to sort the data out. Since each site has different formatting, I need to sort each of them differently.

And since I compare 2 of them, I only need to sort 2 of them. In order to do this I need to know which site is selected first and which one is second. And My code below evaluates this with **if and elif for each of the sites**. With each website added to the dictionary, I found a solution to write another if and elif statements.

My question is: how can I only execute the related sites' sorting code 
 without using if and elif pairs for each website? Is there a pythonic or programmatic way of doing this?

My func is:

```
def getpairs(xx,yy):
    mydict = {1:"http://1stsite.com", 2:"http://2ndsite.com", ... , 6:"http://6thsite.com" }
    with urllib.request.urlopen(mydict[xx]) as url:
    dataone = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    with urllib.request.urlopen(mydict[yy]) as url:
    datatwo = json.loads(url.read().decode())

    if xx == 1:
        sorted1 = some code to sort 1st website data(dataone list)
        dataxx = sorted1
    elif yy == 1:
        sorted1 =some code to sort 1st website data(datatwo list)
        datayy = sorted1
    if xx == 2:
    ...
    ...
    ...
    if xx == 6:
        sorted6 = some code to sort 6th website data(dataone list)
        dataxx = sorted6
    elif yy == 6:
        sorted6 = some code to sort 6th website data(datatwo list)
        datayy = sorted6
    compared = set(dataxx).intersection(datayy)
    return compared
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another dictionary with the sorting functions, indexed in the same way that `mydict` is indexed, or perhaps with the URLs. Something like this:

```
def sorting_function_1(data):
    ...

def sorting_function_2(data):
    ...

def sorting_function_3(data):
    ...

SORTING_FUNCTIONS = {
    1: sorting_function_1,
    2: sorting_function_2,
    3: sorting_function_3,
    4: sorting_function_2,
    5: sorting_function_1,
    ...
}

def fetch_data(url, sorting_function):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
        data = json.loads(response.read().decode())
        sorted_data = sorting_function(data)
        return sorted_data

def getpairs(xx, yy):
    mydict = { ... }
    dataxx = fetch_data(mydict[xx], SORTING_FUNCTIONS[xx])
    datayy = fetch_data(mydict[yy], SORTING_FUNCTIONS[yy])
    ...
```

I hope this help.

Comment: SORTING_FUNCTIONS dictionary worked out great for me, thank you very much. But now that dictionary is not inside of the function, every time I run the code all of the sorting functions recalculated. Is there a workaround for this ?

Comment: I’m glad that it worked for you. I don’t quite understand your follow-up question. Specifically, I don’t understand what you mean by “recalculated”. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: In your code SORTING_FUNCTIONS dictionary is not in any of the functions. Thus all the sorting_functions inside the dict is calculated even if I pick 2 of them. It is not a big deal since run time is not a problem. But it would be nice to know if there is a way not to run every other sorting func that is not stated in the getpairs func.

Comment: I see. I wouldn't be concerned about that. They don't actually run; they are just referenced in the dictionary. If you will define a very large, unmanageable number of sorting functions, you may want to consider an object-oriented approach using the  Strategy pattern, or analyze what's common and what's not common among your sorting functions and look for a way to code the common stuff and extract the rest into configuration. Good luck!

Comment: I am new to programming so I'll check "Strategy pattern" in case I needed. Thank you for your help